# Dynamically select column from data frame in function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame from which I want to select a column. For that purpose I have defined a function. The name of the column is provided as parameter:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE))

f1 <- function(data, name)
{
  data[name]
}

f1(d, "x")
f1(d, "y")
```

However, instead of providing the column **name** as character string I would like to provide the column as symbol as in this form:

```
f2(d, x)
f2(d, y)
```

My question: How is `f2` to be defined?

Background: This is a simplified example. Actually the function to be defined has this prototype:

```
fx(d, v, ...)
```

and returns a data frame which sums up`v` over any column listed in `...`.

Comment: @Arun call to `aggregate` whith parameter `by=<...>` und function `sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `deparse(substitute(name))`, i.e.

```
f2 <- function(data, name)
    data[deparse(substitute(name))]
```

For example:

```
data <- data.frame(id=1:5, val=letters[1:5])
f2(data, val)
##  val
##1   a
##2   b
##3   c
##4   d
##5   e
```

For multiple columns selection you may use:

```
f3 <- function(data, ...) {
   cols <- sapply(as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)], as.character)
   data[cols]
}
```

Which gives e.g.:

```
f3(data, val, id)
##   val id
## 1   a  1
## 2   b  2
## 3   c  3
## 4   d  4
## 5   e  5
```